# YEAR as an input

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

There is a table in my SQL Server called `Product` and the columns are `ID, NAME, YEAR, COST`

**Sample data:**

```
ID   NAME     YEAR            COST
----------------------------------                                           
1        A      2006 05 03     4
2        B      2006 04 01     5
3        C      2001 05 01     6
4        D      2002 05 02     7
5        E      2003 04 01     8
```

I want to take only the YEAR as an input like 2006 as an input and i want an output that shows all the added cost of that year. HOW can i do this?

**Expected output:**

```
ID   NAME    YEAR         TOTAL
-------------------------------
1     A      2006 05 03     9
2     B      2006 02 01     9
3     C      2001 05 01     6
4     D      2002 05 02     7
5     E      2003 04 01     8
```

Comment: I don't get it at all

Comment: The cost value of the input year will be added and shows as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using sub query:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, year, (select  Sum(Cost)
                         from Product  P1
                         where YEAR(P1.year) = YEAR(P2.year)) as Cost
FROM Product P2
WHERE YEAR(year) = 2006 --your parameter here
```

demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9345d/10

stored procedure with parameter would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Year int  

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select ID, Name, year, (select  Sum(Cost)
                         from Products P1
                         where YEAR(P1.year) = YEAR(P2.year)) as Cost
    from Products P2
    WHERE YEAR(year) = @Year
END
GO
```

Comment: Can it is possible by using procedure?

Comment: Yes i want that but the main thing is i want the sum value of that year using procedure as when i take the input i will give the total year like "2006-05-03" and it will take only 2006 and as a result shows the 2006-05-03 and 2006-04-01 added cost. Can you do this by creating stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sum()` with an `over()` clause and partition by `year()`.

```
select T.ID,
       T.Name,
       T.Year,
       sum(T.Cost) over(partition by year(T.Year)) as Cost 
from YourTable as T
```

[SUM (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx)
[OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
[YEAR (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e093/1)

Filtering the above query on a parameter `@Year` would look like this:

```
select T.ID,
       T.Name,
       T.Year,
       sum(T.Cost) over() as Cost 
from YourTable as T
where T.Year >= dateadd(year, @Year-1900, '19000101') and
      T.Year < dateadd(year, @Year-1899, '19000101')
```

Comment: Actually i want to take the year as an input.How can i do this? As i only take 2006 from the year but wants the output from both 2006-05-03 and 2006-04-01.
Can i use procedure?

Comment: @user3158245 Your expected output contains all rows. Don't want that?

Comment: Yes i want that but the main thing is i want the sum value of that year using procedure as when i take the input i will give the total year like "2006-05-03" and it will take only 2006 and as a result shows the 2006-05-03 and 2006-04-01 added cost.

Comment: @user3158245 Ok, not sure I understand what you want here but I have updated the answer with a version that filters the output on year. The parameter `@Year` should be an integer with the value of 2006.